# Android Retrofit api link presntation

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm still beginner on retrofit API for android, but I still didn't get it !!
I know about the Annotation `@Path` and `@Query` but I still don't know what is the use of `@Field` 
and I also know about `@POST` and `@GET` but I don't know what is `@PUT`
and one last question.. lets say that in my API I created the following service.

```
@GET("/bookmarks")


public abstract void bookmarks(@Query("countryCode") String paramString, @Query("limit") int paramInt1, Callback<BookmarksResult> paramCallback);
```

how this call is actually presented as a link?? I mean would it be like this

```
http://www.example.com/api/bookmarks?countryCode=X&limit=X
```

please some help my whole day on this and I still don't have good answers
thanks

Comment: if your `baseUrl` is `http://www.example.com/api` the answer is yes. I  would use `@QueryMap` instead of passing more than one `@Query`

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks ^_^ is this the same case for POST & PUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `baseUrl` is http://www.example.com/api the answer is yes. The url will be resolved in

```
http://www.example.com/api/bookmarks?countryCode=X&limit=X
```

and the same applies for the other request methods.

I would use `@QueryMap` instead of passing more than one `@Query`, but that's more a matter of taste.

I just notice that your method is marked as `abstract`. I am pretty sure that one of the constraints of retrofit is that you have to use an interface to declare your endpoints

Comment: one question... what is the use of Annotation @Field?

Comment: @Field is for Post/Put, when you use  the form-encoded request

Comment: then if I have @Field("countryCode") String paramString the link also would be the same as http://www.example.com/api/bookmarks?countryCode=X&limit=X

Comment: It shouldn't, if you annotate the method with `@FormUrlEncoded`. I am not sure tough